# How to achieve the snapchat swipe transition between views?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, swipe, uipangesturerecognizer

Does anyone know how to achieve the seamless swiping between views that snapchat have. My best guess is a method using the UIPanGestureRecognizer which performs a segue but that doesn't quite achieve the effect of being able to see both views.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They are probably using a [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html) to get that effect.